# Help connecting Clawfoot tub

Tags: bathtub, leaking

[image]I have an old clawfoot tub on the second floor. I have the first floor bathroom fully demoed for a renovation. my kid was showering upstairs and I saw it was leaking into the first [image]floor. The leak is coming from this connection above the second floor. What’s the best way to connect these two parts? I do have the ability to cut the PVC below, and squeeze in a new part above.

Including pictures, above and below.

Comment: Remove the broken nut and see that the brass pipe that comes down is still good. Otherwise you're probably looking at a whole new assembly, as that piece of pipe has tiny threads that go inside the part that looks like it's missing a nut (bottom of the tee). But I guess that's what the extra nut pictured here is for https://www.amazon.com/Eastman-35201-Overflow-Chrome-Plated/dp/B00838ITCW?source=ps-sl-shoppingads-lpcontext&ref_=fplfs&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&th=1 - to put a pvc tail piece there? But your threads are looking cruddy, so....

Comment: Last one I did this was the trouble spot. Had to re-use the old 'tail piece' because no parts from a replacement kit would fit any of the old stuff and I really didn't want to have to pop the overflow and the shoe off a 100yo tub. - Where's the trap?

Comment: That part looks correct thank you. Is the PVC connected to the brass on that part? If it is, I’d have to lift the whole tub to get it in there. If not, I can screw it in from above and attach the PVC from below. Much easier. What do you recommend?

Comment: Yeah you have to lift it. and not drop it on its bespoke inner-threaded irreplaceable tail piece. But since you need to add a trap anyway.... Cut the PVC below; pull it all off the brass. What are we looking at. - It's a can of worms that's what. - Jack's thing looks neat but IDT the threads match.

Comment: First off, I would recommend determining the size/threading of your tub waste outlet. Many are assuming here it is 1 1/2, but many old tubs used 1 3/8. Then you need to figure out how to connect a trap and vent from below. That tub must be rather stinky, not having a trap and all.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the PVC from the tub, clean off the brass threads and install a transition fitting, female pipe thread to PVC, similar to the one shown below. Then connect a new PVC run as needed.

[image]

https://www.supplyhouse.com/Everflow-BRCPF112-NL-1-1-2-CPVC-x-Female-Brass-Adapter-Lead-Free?utm_source=google_ad&utm_medium=Shopping_tm&utm_campaign=Shopping_TM_New_users&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAtOmsBhCnARIsAGPa5ybamgVRvQ-GYsvQmpRZrYSUqRLpu0Mp-DMUn_krIDWDIbEP76mQhAkaAp83EALw_wcB

Comment: The leak is above the connection that you're replacing, no? I suspect that somebody abused that nut as a make-shift band aid for a puncture.

Comment: Yes, the work is bad. But how do you fix it?

Comment: @DouglasLevere  That PVC nut is trying to join the brass threads to the PVC adapter.  Cut that nut away, pull out/cut the PVC out from below and get a transition fitting similar tothe one I showed.